# Proof that every polyhedron admits a triangulation

Tags: low-dimensional-topology

Remark 3 in [this text](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/287xnotes/Lecture17.pdf) claims that every polyhedron admits a triangulation, but this is not obvious to me and I was not able to find a proof that I could understand (only some complicated computer science algorithms).

Does someone know an easy proof?

Comment: Have you found an answer since the time you asked this? If so, would you mind posting it?

Comment: @Blazej afraid not. I ended up assuming that $K$ was compact which was always the case for the application I needed it for. That way we can cover $K$ by a finite number of simplices and then use barycentric subdivision to turn that collection into a simplicial complex.